# .NET ASP.NET Web Application - Continous Integration Solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, mercurial, continuous-integration

Is there a way to automate building and publishing a project to our development server from our Mercurial Hg repository?

I'd like it to occur when a new revision is stored in source control.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood what you're looking for (your question is hard to understand), but to recap: You are looking for a way for your project to be built and published each time a revision is committed to your source control system, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. I'm not native english speaker maybe that question is not writed clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CruiseControl.NET](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet), as I can see it suports Mercurial as Version Control.

Answer (score 2):

[Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is able to build VS solutions extracted from SVN, GIT, Mercurial and others and publish the results of your builds; it have many many plugins, connectors, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I used SubVersion (SVN) together with [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for doing the same.

Comment: TeamCity also supports Mercurial.